# How to get Persian And Arabic Characters in php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, ascii, farsi

I Want To Get Ascii Code from Persian characters.

My Code:

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 
$Char = "س"; // This is a Persian Character
echo ord($Char); // Output: 216
echo ord(utf8_encode($Char)); // Output: 195
// The Real Code Of This Character: 1587
?>
```

Comment: See also `htmlentities("س")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [mb_ord()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord.php) to get the code point of a multibyte character :

```
$Char = "س"; // This is a Persian Character
echo mb_ord($Char); // Output: 1587
```